# How to install additional pip for python3.4?

Tags: pip, python-3.4

I usually use python 3.7 on my ubuntu but in order to run a brainfuck jupyter notebook (from https://github.com/robbielynch/ibrainfuck) I need to run python3.4. So I installed python3.4 using

```
wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.4.0/Python-3.4.0.tgz
tar xzvf Python-3.4.0.tgz
cd python3.4/
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

which worked well and I can run python3.4 by typing `$ python3.4` in the terminal.

Well, now I tried to install pip for python3.4 as follows:

```
wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
sudo python3.4 get-pip.py
```

And got a `RuntimeError: Python 3.5 or later is required` error.

Any ideas, how to install pip for python3.4?

Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 0):

You can type `python3.4 -m pip install <SomePackage>`. The python documentation has a [section](https://docs.python.org/3/installing/index.html#work-with-multiple-versions-of-python-installed-in-parallel) about how to install packages when working with multiple installations.

Comment: Does not work. Forgot to mention that pip is not installed for python3.4 yet...

Comment: pip has dropped support for python 3.4 starting with version 19.0. You can try specifying the version of pip you wish to install using `sudo python3.4 get-pip.py pip==18.1`

Comment: does not work. Even if I try to install pip8.0.0, I get the ```RuntimeError: Python 3.5 or later is required``` error

Comment: This is what I get, if I try to install ```https://bootstrap.pypa.io/3.4/get-pip.py```:

```Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.",)) - skipping
  ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pip<19.2 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pip<19.2```

Comment: You might be missing the SSL libraries. Have you tried `sudo apt-get install libssl-dev`?

Comment: No, libssl-dev is installed

Comment: Are you sitting behind a proxy? If so, you might need to run it like `sudo python3.4 get-pip.py --proxy="http://[user:passwd@]proxy.server:port" pip==18.1`